# React Change Listener not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I know this question has been asked several times, I have tried different solutions so far and none of them seem to work. I am new to React, I am teaching myself, I have a table and a `Pagination div` at the bottom, the pagination div looks like this

```
 <Pagination
  count={response.payLoad.totalPages}
  defaultPage={1}
  page={page}
  variant="outlined"
  shape="rounded"
  onChange={this.handleOnPageChange}
/>
```

And the `handleOnPageChange` looks like this

```
handleOnPageChange = (event, page) => {
  console.log("Page selected: " + page);
  this.setState({ currentPage: page });
  this.populateTable();
}
```

The `onChange` method has two parameters, `event`, `page`, the `handleOnPageChange` method is supposed to catch the event and print a console message that says `Page selected`+pageNumber and load new data in the `table` with the `populateTable()` method but to my surprise nothing happens, not even the console message is printed out, where can I be going wrong?

Pagination is from the `material-ui` lib

```
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';
```

The `populateTable()` method

```
populateTable() {
    this.fetchUsers(this.state.currentPage);
}


 async fetchUsers(page) {
    fetch('/api/v1/users/'+page+'/10')
        .then(response => response.json() )
        .then(data => this.setState({ users: data, loading: false })).catch(); 

}
```

Comment: IS Pagination a custom component or from some library? If its a custom component can you show its code

Comment: Did you properly bind the handleOnPageChange method to this ?

Comment: Can you include `this.populateTable();` in your question, it will help addressing the issue.

Comment: @ROOT I have added

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri its from the material lib, please check my updated question

Comment: @Striped How do you properly bind it? I am new and usually this is how I call methods when am using ordinary `jQuery` and `JS`

Comment: You may want to pass `page` to `populateTable` so it isn't using stale state, or use `componentDidUpdate` to trigger the fetch when state *does* update with the new `page`.

Comment: is `Pagination` inside class or function component?

Comment: @Striped and Hagai It's an arrow function in a class-based component, I think `this` being bound is a safe assumption.

Comment: @HagaiHarari it is an import from `@material-ui/lab/Pagination`

Comment: Sandy, please remove all but the console log from the `handleOnPageChange` callback and test. If that works then add line-by-line until it stops working.

Comment: @DrewReese I have just tried it and to no avail

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in a codesandbox using the props copied from your snippet. Can you try to create and share a codesandbox that repros the issue?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the overwhelming response, it turns out the function that renders my `table` together with my `pagination` is a `static`

```
static renderResults(results){

  <div>
   <table>
    ....
  </table>
 <Pagination
  count={response.payLoad.totalPages}
  defaultPage={1}
  page={page}
  variant="outlined"
  shape="rounded"
  onChange={this.handleOnPageChange}/>
}
```

Not sure if the same applies to `Javascript` but in `Java` you cannot access the `this` from a `Static`, I feel that is the reason nothing was happening, the moment I removed it, everything worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. Glad you got it sorted out.